# Delete elasticsearch records by query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a code that find records what I need:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/one/two/_search" -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "range" : {
        "timestamp" : { "gte" : "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z", "lt" : "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z||+1M"}
    }
  }
}'
```

Now I want to transform it to code that will delete these records.

According to [this doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) I tried to change *_search* to *query* and got:

```
{"_index":"one","_type":"two","_id":"_query","found":false}
```

I tried to change *XGET* to *XDELETE*:

```
{"found":false,"_index":"one","_type":"two","_id":"_search","_version":1}
```

Elasticsearch version:

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "1.0.3",
    "build_hash" : "61bfb72d845a59a58cd9910e47515665f6478a5c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-04-16T14:43:11Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.6"
  }
```

What is the right query to delete these records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use delete by query to delete documents which match your query, but instead of using _search you need to say _query

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/one/two/_query" -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "range" : {
        "timestamp" : { "gte" : "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z", "lt" : "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z||+1M"}
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent an hour staring at it and not noticing _query vs _search.